# We are doing "groups" in creating Rock, Paper, Scissors. We are using 1 for rock, 2 for paper, and 3 for scissors

Tags: java

```
 else if (userChose == "1")
   {
      if (compChose == "2")
      {
         System.out.println("You Win!");
      {

      else 
      {
         (compChose == "3");
         System.out.println("You lose!");
      {
   }
```

It keeps saying that this code for every example is not a sentence?
        compChose == "3";

Comment: also my variables are correct compChose and userChose. I established them at the beginning. I just didn't add that because I am only getting 8 errors and it's part of this.

Comment: What is `compChose`? Please provide an [MCVE]

Comment: `(compChose == "3");` is not a valid statement.

Comment: Also, all your conditional logic will fail, because that's not [how you compare strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: It is right, `compChose == "3";` is not a statement, it's an expression. Perhaps you meant `if (compChose == "3")`?

Comment: Why does your code have 5 `{` start-braces and only 1 `}` end-brace?

Comment: Im not comparing strings? Im comparing the button they will press from jbutton 1, 2, or 3....

int userChose, compChose;

Comment: @OhioState When you enclose them in quotation marks they become `String`'s

Comment: @OhioState Then change `if (compChose == "2")` to `if (compChose == 2)`

Comment: @Andreas maybe that's what i mean? Idk im a little confused and our teacher doesn't help.  

userChose = userPick();
compChose = computerPick();
winner = determineWinner(userChose, compChose);

Comment: @GBlodgett shitt I knew that didnt look right. Im sorry. I'm flustered. I think Im overthinking my section. Its hard only doing a section of a code. I would have rather done the whole project myself

Comment: Okay so it compiles now!  Although, I feel like it doesn't look right because I have a ton of if statements within the main if else

Answer (score 0):

You should compare strings in java using the equals-method that comes with these String-objects. Here's an example:

```
string1 = "This is a text";
string2 = "This is a text";
System.out.println(string1.equals(string2));
```

The result would be true.

I also recommend looking into [switch-statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) if you are going to have a lot of if-statements to check for user input. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was getting my strings and integer methods switched up.  I did see switch statements in my textbook but the teacher said she didn't like those. I thought it would look nicer/easier.  Thank you all for the help!!

Comment: @OhioState I am glad to help! I got no idea why people are downvoting my answer, but you could upvote the answer and accept it as a solution to your problem? :)

Comment: @OhioState [You said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786065/we-are-doing-groups-in-creating-rock-paper-scissors-we-are-using-1-for-rock/52786122#comment92493645_52786065) `userChose` is an `int`. Are you now saying it's a `String`? If so, [azurefrog already told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786065/we-are-doing-groups-in-creating-rock-paper-scissors-we-are-using-1-for-rock/52786122#comment92493598_52786065) how to compare strings.

Comment: @Nystuen If the problem is that variables are `String` variables, even though OP said they were `int` variables, and that solution is to call `equals()`, then question should be closed as duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/5221149), and it shouldn't be answered, which I believe is why this answer has been down-voted. In an attempt to keep StackOverflow clean, we don't want a lot of redundant answers.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you very much for clarifying!

Comment: its an int. I didnt mean to try to compare strings. Sorry for this bad question guys. I was very confused myself